# How to extend HTML container objects around relative child elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="banner-success"> 
    <span class="banner-text">
        You were successful! Yay! Some long reason what your success
        implies goes here.
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Add future banners to this style, this is generic banner styling*/
.banner-success
{
    background-position: 5px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 42px;
    padding-left: 47px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*Create a new entry in this section for each banner, with appropriate image and
colors*/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.banner-success
{
    color: #004400;
    background-color: #DDF2E4;
    background-image: url("../Images/Success.gif");
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.banner-text
{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

This allows for a standard banner, each with an image and arbitrary lines of text, assuming a consistent image size. My issue is that the div is being sized as if the text within isn't being pushed down, and so the bottom line of the text reaches outside of the div.

Is there a way to tell a div, or any container element, 'be as big as your constituent elements are, AFTER they've been relatively positioned to you'?

Comment: The resizing you mention is normal behavior, I think... maybe you mean you want to stretch the background image?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but in my experience, you'd better give the parent element `position:relative` property, if you want its child element to has `top:`, `left:`, etc. properties.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow:hidden` to the .banner-success.

I made a couple of tweaks to even out the padding around your text (and subbed a background
image so you could see it working w/ an image in place):

http://jsfiddle.net/qTsgL/

Cheers!